# shell command contains pipe, will child_process.exec() wait for all to finish before calling callback?

Tags: node.js

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback
has example like this,

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const child = exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l',
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
    }
});
```

There's a pipe in the shell command in the exec(), my question is, is the callback get called after "cat" finishes or after "wc" finishes ?

what happens to this case:

```
const child = exec('cat *.js; ls -l', callback);
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran an example, `exec()` as any function with a callback in Javascript; executes everything if no error before callback is triggered.

JSON file as an example:

```
[
  {
    "test" : {
      "test1" : 1,
      "test2" : 2,
      "test3" : "this is a string"
    }
  }  
]
```

Code:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const child = exec('cat json.json | wc -l',
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ', error);
    }
  }
);
```

Output:

```
stdout:       9
```

Comment: Very good to know that, wish i can see this explicitly in the document.